# Large Image Not Showing in ImageView using Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

This is my [Image](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/exo-player-b8500.appspot.com/o/pdf_img%2Fsheet_two.jpg?alt=media&token=0e59f4f6-9e6f-40da-98a7-0d95f222c0c4)

I want to show `ImageView` with `ScrollView`

Code:

```
  Picasso.get().load(img_url2)
            .fit().centerInside()
            .into(imageView2);
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dddddd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend some days to find solution. below I add entire necessary code

**In Manifest**

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

**In XML file**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dddddd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
            app:zoomage_doubleTapToZoom="true"
            app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
            app:zoomage_zoomable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**In Java Code**

```
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(pdf_link)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
```

**In Dependency**

```
implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Image view to show Proportional.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class ProportionalImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {
 
    public ProportionalImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
 
    public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
 
    public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        }
        else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Use this ImageView as below

```
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/actionBar">

            <com.dukaan.customviews.ProportionalImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/actionBar" />
        </ScrollView>
```

Then after setting the image, as usual, using Glide or Picasso.

I prefer to set like below

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(url.equals("") ? R.drawable.task_info_image : url)
            .addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, 
                   Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean 
                      isFirstResource) {
                         dataBinding.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    dataBinding.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dataBinding.ivBanner.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(dataBinding.ivBanner);
```

It's showing as your expectation.

Comment: Thanks for your effect , but i wanna Picasso or Glide library

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your didn't add any image to imageView without layout size.
First of all you should add image to the imageView. To do this follow this step

1  Copy your image and paste at drawable file(app-res-drawable).then make it file name

2  add this line to your imageView

`android:background="@drawable/file-name`

Comment: i have a huge image so i should use cloud storage